# Information regarding old AB (Allen bradley) potentiometer JAIN056S102MA

Tags: datasheet, potentiometer

i was looking for information (datasheet) regarding this old potentiometer from 1962 on the internet, JAIN056S102MA type J, 1k-ohm from Allen Bradley and i was not able to find any information about it, i want to replace it because it is not working anymore and it is in a working machine, according from a user of this forum this potentiometer is Type J, 1k-ohm pot that is rated at 2 watts end-to-end and has an an audio taper, what does it mean audio taper?, anyone can help me where to get the datasheet of this pot?, anyhelp is really aprecciated, thank you very much

Omar Torres

Comment: Have you tried searching the internet for explanations of audio taper potentiometers?

Comment: thank you very much for your answer back, i already did it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [LINK](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1580637.pdf) to a PDF data sheet. It decodes the entire part number and indicates that the "M" taper is linear.

Here is a picture of the same part number potentiometer except that it has the U (+/-10%) linear taper instead of the M (+/-20%) linear taper.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your information, it really helped me a lot, thank you